Echarts.js Sankey Diagram Levels not working
In Echarts Sankey, they have an example with levels.
However, when I try to run it (only change is vertically, though this doesn't seem to influence), it does not align the nodes by level.
<script>
// See below for JSON based Sankey
// https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=sankey-levels
// https://echarts.apache.org/examples/data/asset/data/product.json

var chartDom = document.getElementById('flow');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

myChart.showLoading();

$.get('../api/stream_data/{{item.id}}', function (data) {
  myChart.hideLoading();
  myChart.setOption(
    (option = {
       // grid: {
       //   left: 0,
       //   top: 0,
       //   right: 0,
       //   bottom: 0
       // },
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        triggerOn: 'mousemove'
      },
      //legend: {
      //  textStyle: {
      //    fontSize: '15',
      //  }
      //},
      series: [
        {
          type: 'sankey',
          orient: 'vertical',
          label: {
              position: 'top',
              textStyle: {
                fontSize: 24
              },
              formatter: '{b}: {c}%'
          },

          data: data.nodes,
          links: data.links,
          emphasis: {
                    focus: 'adjacency'
                  },
          levels: [
            {
              depth: 0,
              itemStyle: {
                color: '#fbb4ae'
              },
              lineStyle: {
                color: 'source',
                opacity: 0.6
              }
            },
            {
              depth: 1,
              itemStyle: {
                color: '#b3cde3'
              },
              lineStyle: {
                color: 'source',
                opacity: 0.6
              }
            },
            {
              depth: 2,
              itemStyle: {
                color: '#ccebc5'
              },
              lineStyle: {
                color: 'source',
                opacity: 0.6
              }
            },
            {
              depth: 3,
              itemStyle: {
                color: '#decbe4'
              },
              lineStyle: {
                color: 'source',
                opacity: 0.6
              }
            }
          ],

        
          lineStyle: {
            curveness: 0.5
          },
          label: {
            formatter: '{b}: {c}%',
            position: 'top',
          size: 24
          }
        }
      ]
    })
  );
});

option && myChart.setOption(option);
</script>

Does anybody know what Im doing wrong?
Is there perhaps a better library to generate Sankey in JS which handles this better?

Note, that levels only specifies the appearance of data items in each level. The position of each data item is determined by an iterative algorithm to minimize the overlapping between nodes and edges. It is possible to influence how many iterations this algorithm should do via layoutIterations. If set to 0 the items will be placed in order of the original data (and aligned by level).
I dont know other packages very well but plotly allows to specify exact node positions.
